# Bard seems to be better at multiplication than GPT-4, how did Bard achieve this?

Tags: neural-networks

For example, I asked both Bard and GPT-4 the question: "what is 3238*323729."

Bard gave the correct answer "3238 multiplied by 323 729 is 1048234502.", while GPT-4 gave "The product of 3238 and 323729 is 1,048,167,642.", which is incorrect.

I have tried prompting GPT-4 with chain-of-thought prompting (like "do it step by step"), it still doesn't get the correct answer.

This is just one example and I have repeatedly confirmed this toying with Bard and GPT-4 over arithmetic.

If Bard did not call to a calculator but actually achieved this solely using the trained LLM, it is quite amazing to me.

So my question is, did Bard use a calculator, and if not, how did Bard achieve this accuracy? Or, maybe I should ask, in what different way was Bard trained compared to GPT-4 that give it this much much better ability in arithmetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, seems better than Claude too. I don't think it's calling a calculator (though not sure I could tell if it was). Seems like it's because they integrated some stuff from PaLM:

http://web.archive.org/web/20230531195809/https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-enhances-bards-math-logic-capabilities/483678/

Comment: Welcome to Artificial Intelligence! Whilst this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please note that answers that rely entirely on external links and do not include the information in the post itself may be removed.